# Applying Separate Where Clauses to Separate Columns (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

Is it possible to do something along these lines in a simplistic manner. I know this doesn't make sense but it's what I would like to try and do:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(T.SALES) WHERE T.YEAR = '2018'
,  SUM(T.SALES) WHERE T.YEAR = '2019'    
FROM TABLE1 AS T
```

A longer method I thought of is:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(T.SALES) FROM TABLE1 AS T WHERE T.YEAR = '2018') AS "2018 TOTAL SALES"
 ,(SELECT SUM(T.SALES) FROM TABLE1 AS T WHERE T.YEAR = '2019') AS "2019 TOTAL SALES"
```

But it doesn't really make sense. It does what I want it to do in MySQL but it's not a standardised approach. Any help with this would be fantastic.

I basically want to have 2 columns returned (Total Sales) but each of the columns having it's own separate filter (filtered by year, one by 2018 and the other by 2019), if this is possible to do in an easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can count with conditions:

```
SELECT   
, SUM(case when T.YEAR = '2018' then T.SALES end) "2018 TOTAL SALES"
, SUM(case when T.YEAR = '2019' then T.SALES end) "2019 TOTAL SALES"
FROM TABLE1 AS T
```

Comment: It's worth explaining that the way `CASE` expressions work is if there is no match, it returns NULL, and NULL is typically ignored by aggregate functions such as SUM().

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you for explanation

Comment: Brilliant, thank you both. Exactly what I am looking for!